# How to get native screen resolution with Intel Z370 Exress Chipset

Tags: intel-graphics, 17.10

I assembled a new computer with the following configuration.

- Intel i7 8700K
- Gigabyte Z370M D3H motherboard (Intel Z370 express chipset)

When I boot windows, I am getting a native resolution of 1920X1080. But in ubuntu, I am getting only 1024X768. I am using an Acer monitor connected via VGA using a HDMI VGA converter.

I have tried all possible solutions discussed online, with `xrandr` etc. But no luck so far. `xrandr` is detecting the display as just `default`.

I am running Ubuntu 17.07 with kernel 4.13.0.

Any idea how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a review by Phoronix of [Intel UHD Graphics 630 on Linux](http://www.phoronix.com/vr.php?view=25319) a kernel 4.13 or newer and the kernel commandline switch `i915.alpha_support=1` are required to enable the graphics drivers.

[According to Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/vr.php?view=25396): "That will change with the Linux 4.15 kernel where Coffeelake/UHD Graphics are enabled unconditionally."

However, on a PC with an ASUS ROG Strix Z370-E Gaming mainboard and Intel Core i5-8400 CPU Linux kernel 4.13 from `linux-image-4.13.0-16-generic` in conjunction with `i915.alpha_support=1` did not help. Installing a Linux kernel 4.15 rc6 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ provided the high screen resolutions.

(We haven't tried other kernels.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 17.10 and asus z370-h motherboard.

I solve this by installing Ubuntu 16.04.
Why 16.04? because I needed to install [Intel Graphics Update Tool for Linux* OS v2.0.2](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2) which is not supported in 17.10. Once you install this tool, you can update the Intel drivers but this is not all. I had to update the Linux kernel. You can do it this way:

To check the actual kernel version type in a terminal: `uname -sr`

1. In the terminal, download the last and stable files:

   `wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.8/linux-headers-4.14.8-041408_4.14.8-041408.201712200555_all.deb
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.8/linux-headers-4.14.8-041408-generic_4.14.8-041408.201712200555_amd64.deb
   wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.14.8/linux-image-4.14.8-041408-generic_4.14.8-041408.201712200555_amd64.deb`
2. Now execute `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
3. `sudo reboot`
4. Check again the new version of kernel `uname -sr`

I hope this help

Comment: As an update to this info: 
Yesterday I installed GDM3 and  the resolution went back to 1024 x 768px.
I had to uninstall in order to go back to the 192x1080 resolution.