# Upgrade to Kernel 4.13 (from 4.10) breaks resolution on HP Pavilion monitor

Tags: kernel, display-resolution

I have an HP Pavilion monitor with native resolution of 2560x1440. When performing a recent upgrade on Ubuntu 16.04, the kernel went from 4.10 to 4.13, which limited the resolution of the HP monitor to something like 1280x1024. A Samsung monitor with a resolution of 2048x1152 was unaffected.

I am running on a Zotac with KabyLake i3 processor. An output of lspci shows a graphics processor:

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
```

Switching back to kernel 4.10 restored the normal monitor resolution. Is there anything that can be done to fix this problem with the 4.13 kernel? Should I just keep using the older kernel until a newer kernel update is available?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/811453/w-possible-missing-firmware-for-module-i915-bpo-when-updating-initramfs and look at the second answer where it is pointed out on how to get the Intel Graphics updated drivers for Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Looking at the first answer, I downloaded the various drivers from Intel directly, and they all install i915 drivers. According to this page, https://askubuntu.com/questions/987777/how-to-get-native-screen-resolution-with-intel-z370-exress-chipset , it looks like the i915 drivers won't work with the 4.13 kernel, and it must be upgraded to 4.14. I am somewhat leery of upgrading my kernel beyond the one supplied for 16.04LTS.

Comment: I still don't have a resolution for this issue. I tried a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 18.04.1 and the problem remains. I am unable to upgrade past Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.10. I am not sure what to do. Any current advice?

Comment: Maybe look into what the HorizSync and VertRefresh are for the monitor then add that to the monitor section of the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.  I remember one of my monitors that I am using now the EDID info is not found from it so I had to manually add that to it.  Or maybe look into some of the answers here about getting the EDID info from the monitor as once that is set then usually monitors will do their full resolutions.